# How to describe a double link using separation logic in the VST tool

Tags: coq, verifiable-c

As an example in the VST project, the reverse.c file has a linked list like this:

```
struct list {unsigned head; struct list *tail;};
unsigned sumlist (struct list *p) {
  unsigned s = 0;
  struct list *t = p;
  unsigned h;
  while (t) {
     h = t->head;
     t = t->tail;
     s = s + h;
  }
  return s;
}
```

and it's separation logic is wrote as:

```
SEP (lseg LS sh (map Vint contents) p nullval)
```

in which the LS is defined as:

```
Instance LS: listspec _list _tail (fun _ _ => emp).
Proof. eapply mk_listspec; reflexivity. Defined.
```

My question is if I have a double linked list, how to write its corresponding separation logic.
for example: the double linked list like this:

```
struct list {unsigned head; struct list *prev;struct list *tail;};
```

so, what should be the "`SEP (lseg LS?? sh (map Vint contents) p nullval)`"?

Answer (score 4):

First, I would suggest using "verif_reverse2.v" instead of "verif_reverse.v".  If you don't have a recent version of VST, get VST 2.0 (or get the master branch of the github repo) and look at verif_reverse2.v, and look at the description of this case study in doc/VC.pdf.

Still, that's for singly linked lists.

Googling "doubly linked list separation logic" gives this useful reference:

http://www.eecs.qmul.ac.uk/~gretay/papers/SepLogicIntro.ppt
(see slide 17)

Using the Fixpoint technique shown in verif_reverse2.v, you should be able to adapt that solution.